# Aligning buttons in Dash

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I want to align the my buttons - 'left_button' and 'right_button' so it fits on the edges of each of the right left most corner of the images and right most corner of the images.

right now it looks like this [image of buttons not correctly in positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNCbA.png)

Here is the code for the layouts

any tips would be great. Thanks

```
layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                dbc.Row(
                    dbc.Col(
                        navbar,
                    ),
                ),
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(headwear, width=3),
                        dbc.Col(topwear, width=3),
                    ],
                    justify="center",
                    className="mt-3",
                ),
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(bottomwear, width=3),
                        dbc.Col(footwear, width=3),
                    ],
                    justify="center",
                    className="mt-3",
                ),
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(left_button, width=3),
                        dbc.Col(right_button, width=3),
                    ],
                    justify="center",
                ),
            ],
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Maybe you can try this: `dbc.Col(right_button, width=3, justify="right")`